# Показывать кнопку `Загрузить` только после нажатия

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, javascript

Как сделать чтобы кнопка Загрузить показывалась только после  нажатия редактировать и повесить на кнопу сохранить сделать невидимым  а тот <textarea> сделать обратно в <p>?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
                    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

  <script>
(function($) {
    $.fn.replaceTagName = function(replaceWith) {
        var tags = [],
            i    = this.length;
        while (i--) {
            var newElement = document.createElement(replaceWith),
                thisi      = this[i],
                thisia     = thisi.attributes;
            for (var a = thisia.length - 1; a >= 0; a--) {
                var attrib = thisia[a];
                newElement.setAttribute(attrib.name, attrib.value);
            };
            newElement.innerHTML = thisi.innerHTML;
            $(thisi).after(newElement).remove();
            tags[i - 1] = newElement;
        }
        return $(tags);
    };
})(window.jQuery);

$(function() {
    $('#btnEdit').click(function() {
        $('p#num123').replaceTagName('textarea')
    });
});

  </script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="num123">Мой тэг</p> <button id="btnEdit">Редактировать</button>
<button id="load21">сохранить</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Анатолийй, Перефразируйте, пожалуйста, Ваш вопрос: исправьте грамматические ошибки, правильно расставьте запятые. Если ещё добавите побольше уточняющей информации, то Вы ускорите получение ответа.

Comment: @VenZell когда нажимается кнопка редактировать.
1)<p> становится textarea появляется кнопка сохранить
2)Нажимается кнопка сохранить и <textarea> становится обратно в <p>  а кнопка сохранить исчезает
Как?

Comment: @Анатолийй а в чем собственно проблема ? у вас уже всё есть, после нажатия edit делайте `$('#load21').show()` по умолчанию кнопку не показывайте, на нажатие #load21 вызываете replaceWith('p') и чего вы там делаете для save(), кнопку скрывайте.

Comment: а зачем вы вообще тэг с id указываете ? id уникален.

Comment: @eicto конкретный номер id будет формироваться через php

Comment: @Анатолийй зачем "p#num123" а не "#num123" ? p тут не нужен совершенно. а вообще генерировать js через php дурная затея, сделайте лучше нормальную связку между кнопками и элементом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[[@eicto](/users/11304/eicto)](/users/11304/eicto)

```
    $(function() {
    $('#btnEdit').click(function() {
        $('p#num123').replaceTagName('textarea');
        $("#load21").show();
    });
});
$(function() {
    $('#load21').click(function() {
        $("#load21").hide();
        $('textarea#num123').replaceTagName('p');
    });
});
```

но как сделать чтобы потом еще и сохранялось редактированное содержимое?